# Discord Bot error 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

so I´m implementing some simple responses for my bot which used to work, then I implemented a button slash command and it works, but when I try to obtain answers like I did before, it's not working and the error on the title shows up. Here is my code, maybe someone has an answer:

```
def run_discord_bot():
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print (f'{bot.user} is now running!') 



@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    username = str(message.author)
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel)

    print(f"{username} said '{user_message}' ({channel})" )

    if user_message[0] == '?':
        user_message = user_message[1:]
        if message.content:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
    else:
        if message.content:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

@bot.slash_command(description = "This is a test")
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("this is a button", view=MyView())


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace as it is difficult to find where the bug is in your code.